# Maxwell and Bianchi equations

Tags: electromagnetism, action

We frequently see: A certain action and then we are asked to solve for Bianchi identity and Maxwell equation.

I have often solved for them but I never knew what is the difference between the two? In more specific words, I know that Maxwell equation is derived from the action but what does a Bianchi identity mean?

EDIT: Now that in the comments we faced a new issue, I am editing this with a example.

Example: Lagragian is
$$L=-\frac{1}{4}ImZF_{\mu\nu}F{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{8}ReZ\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}F_{\mu\nu}F_{\rho\sigma}$$

So, the book (Van Proeyen's SUGRA book) says tat the equation of motion of this theory will be
$$\partial_{\mu}[(ImZ)F^{\mu\nu}+i(ReZ)\tilde{F}^{\mu\nu}]=0$$
How come this is the same as te usual Maxwell equation $d\star F=0$ (I believe this is a dual teory so maybe the equation Evan presented in the comments will be instead dF=0 but in all cases I could cut the story short and ask
 how did Van Proeyen reach this
$$\partial_{\mu}[(ImZ)F^{\mu\nu}+i(ReZ)\tilde{F}^{\mu\nu}]=0?$$

Answer (score 6):

The difference is perhaps illuminated best in the language of differential forms. Recall that the vector potential $A$ can be considered a 1-form field $A$, which we can act on with the exterior derivative operator $d$ to get the electromagnetic field strength tensor 
\begin{equation}
F=dA.
\end{equation}
Since $F$ is an exact form we know that it is closed. So
\begin{equation}
dF = d^2A=0.
\end{equation}
This is the Bianchi Identity $\nabla_{[\alpha}F_{\beta\gamma]}=0$, expressed in the language of differential forms. Now, another operation that we can apply to a differential form is the Hodge dual operator *, which maps $k$-forms to $(n-k)$-forms in $n$-dimensional space. So, in 4 spacetime dimensions the Hodge dual of the 2-form $F$ will be another 2-form, $*F$. Now, $*F$ is in general not an exact form and so it's exterior derivative need not vanish. Instead, we have
\begin{equation}
d*F=\mu_0 J,
\end{equation}
where $J$ is the current 3-form. This is Maxwell's equations $\partial_{\alpha}F^{\alpha\beta}=\mu_o J^{\beta}$ expressed in the language of differential forms.

Comment: Yes, thank you for mentioning that. But if for example we have, $S=\int{F_{\mu\nu}\tilde{F}_{\mu\nu}}$ and they ask to find the field equations. Then one will have to solve for this: $\frac{\delta S}{\delta F^{\rho\sigma}}=0$ which does not agree with $d\star F= 0$ (if we assume we have no sources). In other words, isn't maxwell equation supposed to obtained from Euler-Lagrange equation?

Comment: @Beyond-formulas It is obtainable from the Euler-Lagrange equations. The trick is that $F$ is not the field that is varied, you must look at $A$ in $F=\mathrm{d}A$. $F$ is the field *strength*, the actual "field" as far as Euler-Lagrange is concerned is the potential $A$.

Comment: Is it always the case? I see people varying the action with respect to F too. @0celo7

Comment: In one post I read @0celo7, it says that if $A$ is not preset explicitly in the action then it is safe to derive with respect to F. Otherwise, one should derive with respect to A.

Comment: @Beyond-formulas That is correct. Even when $A$ appears explicitly you can rewrite in terms of only $F$ but then your expressions will not be manifestly local. That's why it's easier to do everything in terms of $A$.

Comment: @EvanRule Then it is correct to derive it wrt F given the "lagrangian" above, right? If so, how would the maxwell equation you gave me first agree with the Euler Lagrange equation? :(

Comment: @EvanRule Sorry I haven't been precise. I edited my question. I would appreciate it if you could take a look at it.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with SUGRA but I am able to obtain Van Proeyen's result by varying with respect to $A$. I think that the issue of varying with respect to $F$ is very subtle. For example, $F$ has more degrees of freedom than $A$ and does not contain the same topological information as $A$. Given a general $F$ the Poincare lemma only guarantees locally the existence of $A$ such that $F=dA$. I cannot point to exactly how this causes varying with respect to $F$ to fail but I think it is along these lines.